# How to get data from np.array to std::vector in c++ using <numpy/arrayobject.h>?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This is my first question on this site.

First of all, I need to make a module with one function for python in C++, which must work with numpy, using `<numpy/arrayobject.h>`. This function takes one numpy array and returns two numpy arrays. All arrays are one-dimensional.

The first question is how to get the data from a numpy array? I want to collect the information from array in std::vector, so then I can easily work with it C++.

The second: am I right that function should return a tuple of arrays, then user of my module can write like this in python:
`arr1, arr2 = foo(arr)`
?
And how to return like this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for improve how to ask.

Comment: Since you are C++, I would look into [PyBind11](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy includes [lots of functions and macros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html) that make it pretty easy to access the data of an `ndarray` object within a C or C++ extension. Given a 1D `ndarray` called `v`, one can access element `i` with `PyArray_GETPTR1(v, i)`. So if you want to copy each element in the array to a `std::vector` of the same type, you can iterate over each element and copy it, like so (I'm assuming an array of `double`s):

```
npy_intp vsize = PyArray_SIZE(v);
std::vector<double> out(vsize);
for (int i = 0; i < vsize; i++) {
    out[i] = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(PyArray_GETPTR1(v, i));
}
```

One could also do a bulk `memcpy`-like operation, but keep in mind that NumPy `ndarray`s may be mis-aligned for the data type, have non-native byte order, or other subtle attributes that make such copies less than desirable. But assuming that you are aware of these, one could do:

```
npy_intp vsize = PyArray_SIZE(v);
std::vector<double> out(vsize);
std::memcpy(out.data(), PyArray_DATA(v), sizeof(double) * vsize);
```

Using either approach, `out` now contains a copy of the `ndarray`'s data, and you can manipulate it however you like. Keep in mind that, unless you really need the data as a `std::vector`, the NumPy C API may be perfectly fine to use in your extension as a way to access and manipulate the data. That is, unless you need to pass the data to some other function which *must* take a `std::vector` or you want to use C++ library code that relies on `std::vector`, I'd consider doing all your processing directly on the native array types.

As to your last question, one generally uses [`PyArg_BuildValue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) to construct a tuple which is returned from your extension functions. Your tuple would just contain two `ndarray` objects.

Comment: Thank you a lot! So, I can also get information about the shape of a numpy array by calling the function `PyArray_GetArrayParamsFromObject`? And then I want returning object's shape will be the same

Comment: @InFamousX That'll work just fine, but it's more common to use the macros `PyArray_NDIM()` and `PyArray_DIMS()`. The former function is more often used for converting a Python-native object (like a list-of-lists) to an `ndarray`.

Comment: Sorry, but this cycle `for(int ...)` doesn't work properly, because I get from it only zeros.

Comment: @InFamousX That loop should access the data fine, are you sure that the array itself is not all zeros?

Comment: Thank you, I found another way to get the data. My mistake was that I didn't know that float in python is the same as double in c++. That's why I got nothing but zeros.

Comment: Seems like the numpy document is gone. Could you provide with one? I really need it!

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner Updated the link, thanks for letting me know it was out of date.